# System gets confused when I try to close a deleted question

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, deleted-questions

After reopening a deleted question to see if doing so [would cause the author to be notified](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9144962), I tried to re-close [the deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327311/295232). The Close dialog is functional, but when I click the "Close question" button, the question is *not* closed and the system informs me that "this question is now deleted":

[image]

But it already *was* ...

Comment: System assumes that a question is always closed before being deleted, unaware there can be other options. Probably some really ancient part of the code, from times when there weren't such options...

Comment: [The thing we were trying to test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376896/anyone-can-answer-it-now-in-question-reopen-notification-is-not-true-if-its-a)