# "Anyone can answer it now" in question reopen notification is not true if it's a deleted question

Tags: bug, notifications, deleted-questions, vote-to-reopen

For a while now, users have been notified when a question of theirs is reopened:

> Hooray, this question was reopened! Anyone can answer it now.

This notification [is also issued](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9144970#9144970) even if it gets reopened after it's been deleted. It's possible to vote to reopen questions even after they're deleted, and this behavior was [previously reported and the team decided to retain it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222671/377214).

The assertion that anyone can answer the question is incorrect if the question is reopened while deleted: no one can answer a deleted question. It only serves to confuse the new users to whom the notification is intended.

The best way to fix this, which is not technically difficult (unlike removing the sentence if the question is deleted) and doesn't require much internal discussion (unlike reversing the past decision to allow reopen votes on deleted questions) is to remove this notification if the question that was reopened was deleted at the time.

Comment: How often does this actually happen?

Comment: @RobertLongson of course not often enough to justify fix or spending time, but a bug is a bug.